# Why Ajax return xamp localhost index page after success?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my ajax code below

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
        $.post("http://localhost/test",
            {run : "1"},
            function(data,status){
                $("#show").html(data);
            });
    });
```

then after ajax run, localhost index page return and shown in #show.

[image]

and this is my simple codeigniter method:

```
 public function test(){

    $post = $this->input->post("run");

    echo $post;
}
```

What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: if you type in your browser `http://localhost/test` what do you see ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
It's open XAMPP index page! I don't know why!!!

Comment: you are posting to that url and it is showing you the correct response, you should verify if you really want to send the request to that url or somewhere else

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam but my method is what I add to Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set your `base_url` in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/basefoldername/';
```

*and then use `site_url()` or `base_url()` your ajax with controller name*

should be like this :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
        $.post("<?=site_url('controllername/test');?>",
            {run : "1"},
            function(data,status){
                $("#show").html(data);
        });
});
```